# Scaling Postfix/Dovecot-Server

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I looked at a larger installation of my local university of a Mailserver with Postfix/Dovecot. I am trying to archieve the same and looking forward to get any input or search query about how this could be built by myself.

1. There is a mx Record on a mi (mail-in), researching, there are two mail-in-Servers that use dovecot (mx1/mx2). They are both working parallel. (Here I do not know how the best server is selected, there is no secondary MX record with another priority)
   The same seems to apply to the Mail-Out Servers (there are some of them) that a software chooses the best one.
2. There are about 8 Mailbox-Servers (mbx1....), the data is saved on one of these. If I set one domain (f.e. mail-in.xxxx) how can I set up Dovecot to automatically select the correct server.
3. The Server seems to use some type of technical automatization to (re)distribute accounts. Is that a feature that already exists or is this custom coded?

I am looking forward to some keywords I could look into to archieve this kind of setup.
Thanks in advance,

Lukas

Comment: Beware that many helpful mechanisms present in mail server software were rooted in what a single piece of equipment could do in 2006. Hardware improvements have since for many years outperformed the increase in user needs. Nowadays.. even a *large* installation will have a greater share of its complexity invested into reducing the probability or impact of data loss or outages, instead of plain load balancing.

Comment: Hi anx, do you mean that the focus should be more on the backup strategy (data loss)? I want to build the multiple Storage-Server-System to not scale up indefinitely on a single server and to not have a single point of failure. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the following

- Using DNS to distribute incoming SMTP connections between multiple servers. This can be done with multiple A records for outbound email (`smtp.example.net`), and multiple MX records with the same priority for inbound email. (Inbound connections should be fairly evenly distributed between servers if the MX records all have the same priority.)
- Having your front-end inbound servers just foward emails to `username@storage-X.example.net`, where `X` is the ID/number of the storage server that user is allocated to.
- Run a pretty basic postfix/dovecot setup on the storage servers
- Using something like nginx as a load balancer / proxy for IMAP (possibly also for outbound SMTP). This is also capable of authenticating IMAP/SMTP connections and proxying to a specific backend server depending on the auth response. For example you could have multiple nginx servers terminate & authenticate IMAP connections, then proxy to the correct server by using a fairly simple web app that replies with the correct storage server to nginx. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/#mail_auth
- You'll either want to get everything working with SQL auth so all servers communicate with central SQL servers (or a bunch of read-only mirrors), or have some custom code for deploying config/users across the whole lot

I don't think anything that can do this "out of the box" with dovecot/postfix, but it's mainly just down to configuration.

Comment: Hi dear, thank you for this information. This is some great input. I upvoted and it has been recorded.